# Xcode debug executable failed

Tags: xcode, sketchapp

I am working on a sketch plugin project with xcode. A sketch plugin can be understood as a framework bundle. In the scheme of my project, i set the Execatable to Sketch.app ,and i also checed the Debug executable box. When i run my project, i got `Message from debugger: unable to attach` from the console and the Sketch.app cannot be opened. But when the Debug executable box is not checked, my project worked. But without the Debug executable be checked, i cannot debug my code.
Can someone help me out ?
The xcode version is 10.1 and the my mac version is 10.14.6.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErVMT.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Quit Xcode
2. Open the Terminal.app
3. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode`
4. I can Xcode debugging

Comment: Thank you! I spent 2 hours on this and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution 
1. Check if all frameworks are loaded successfully 
 
2. `File Menu -> Project Settings -> "Legacy Build System".` 
 
3. `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Info -> Launch = Automatically`

Comment: "Standard Build System" ?  Do you mean "Legacy Build System" ？ Mine  is "Legacy Build System"

Comment: @Wang Ying Yes, "Legacy Build System"